# how to set heroku env variables to appear in NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, next.js

Somewhat unfamiliar ground for me, but I'm trying to set a banner on my page that says **"Current Env: REVIEW"** or **"Current Env: STAGING"** depending on what phase of my deployment process I'm on in Heroku.

**Currently, I have environment variables on Heroku like this: `CURRENT_ENV: REVIEW`.** However, when I try to access the variables with the logic below, they come up as undefined in my deployed app. I'm curious what the proper approach is to get these variables set up correctly so my app has the ability to detect whether it's in review or staging.

##### _app.ts

```js
  const getCurrentEnv = (): string => {
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV, process.env.CURRENT_ENV);
    // while deployed on heroku logs: PRODUCTION, undefined

    return process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT'
      ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV
      : process.env.CURRENT_ENV;
  };
```

##### .env.production

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV="PRODUCTION"
```

##### .env.development

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV="DEVELOPMENT"
```

Comment: Which `ENV` file did you store `CURRENT_ENV`? Do you have `NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_ENV` stored twice?

Comment: I dont have `current_env` stored anywhere locally, I thought it would be undefined until heroku passed it in (I created a `current_env` variable in heroku, but not locally)

Comment: How are you setting the veriables in heroku? CLI or web dashboard? By CLI try `heroku config:get CURRENT_ENV` to see if heroku is storing the value.

Comment: dashboard, public vars seem to work when i use `NEXT_PUBLIC ...`